# html table download as xlsx

Tags: jquery, html

I have two jquery ui tabs, with each having a html table in it, this script just downloads the both the table, how do i make it to only download the active tab's table to excel ?

```
$("#btnExport").click(function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            //getting data from our table
            var data_type = 'data:application/vnd.ms-excel';
            var table_div = document.getElementById('tabs');
            var table_html = table_div.outerHTML.replace(/ /g, '%20');

            var a = document.createElement('a');
            a.href = data_type + ', ' + table_html;
            a.download = 'exported_table_' + Math.floor((Math.random() * 9999999) + 1000000) + '.xlsx';
            a.click();
          });
```

Fiddle link : https://jsfiddle.net/d19918/nz1yc3x0/10/

Comment: this is aweful code. this is mixed vanilla, mixed jquery and none java at all :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just have to get the correct tab:

```
var table_div = document.querySelector("#tabs [aria-hidden='false']");
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/nz1yc3x0/13/

Comment: after downloading as excel,  Name and ID are printed at bottom, where it should be at first line

Comment: It is. And it has always been so from the very beginning, because you added the `<thead>` last after all of the rows. If you want the header to appear on top in exported excel, add it first before adding the rows: https://jsfiddle.net/nz1yc3x0/14/